# How to display changes when tapping a button inside a cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitableview

I'm using a table view with custom cell. In this custom cell I got a like button. 
when I tap this button I want this one to get colored. I figure how to color this button but I need to do reload data for displaying it with color. But when I call "table.reloadData()" there is a little scroll view stretch automatically.
There is a way to display changes without reloadData() or to disable scrollView stretching?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading just the row that you have clicked on?

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top
```

For some things, though, you shouldn't have to reload at all.  If all you want is to change the background colour of the cell, you can do it like this.  I now notice that you're working in `Objective-C` and my example is `Swift` - hopefully it's still clear enough :-)

First define a custom cell - mine is a simple one with just a label and a button, you will already have something similar.  I'm not sure if you need to change the colour of the cell, or the button, so I have done both

```
import UIKit

class myCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var labelTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cmdButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func cmdButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        cmdButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        print("click \(sender.tag)")
    }
}
```

If you do need to keep a track of which button has been clicked, you will need to set the tag in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - but you may not even need this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell:myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! myCell

    cell.labelTitle.text = data[indexPath.row]
    cell.cmdButton.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}
```

Comment: how odd.  are you sure you have the right `indexPath`?  If you're reacting to the button press within the cell, you won't be starting with `indexPath` - you will need to get that from the button somehow - through the `tag` attribute?  What happens if you hard-code an indexPath, so that whatever button you press, it updates one particular row, just to see how it works?